# Implementation of NT-Xent loss in `torch`

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to implemenet a NT-Xent loss, given that I have two different embeddings `z_A` and `z_B` with shape `[b,d]` where `b` is the batch size and `d` the dimensionality. In my context, the embeddings are *ordered* , in such a way that `(i,j)` is a positive pair if and only if `i==j` and negative otherwise. Given this assumption I have been trying to implement the loss in the following way:

```
def nt_xent_loss(z_A, z_B, temperature=0.07):
    batch_size = z_A.shape[0]
    similarity = torch.exp(torch.mm(z_A, z_B.t().contiguous()) / temperature)
    mask = torch.eye(batch_size, dtype=torch.float32).bool().cuda()
    numerator = torch.sum(similarity * mask, dim=1)
    denominator = torch.sum(similarity * ~mask, dim=1)
    loss = -torch.log(numerator / denominator)
    return loss.mean()
```

I've been observing weird results/convergence so I'm not too sure about the above implementation, also I've been playing a bit with the temperature parameter but that doesn't change that much the outcome. I just wanted double-check this with you here.